# How do I debug WSDL when WSDL2Java fails?

Tags: wsdl, axis, wsdl2java

We are upgrading our web services to use JAX-WS 2.1.
Our current web services was generated java-first and using Axis1 to auto-generate WSDL.

Now we have this auto-generated WSDL and need to generate JAX-WS compliant Java code from it.

I'm using Wsdl2java from Axis2 which should work fine, but when I try to run it on our WSDL I get multiple errors, indicating the generated WSDL was not really well-formed.

Being not so familiar with WSDL and XML name spaces, I find it hard to debug. Could anyone please lend me a hand here?

Currently I'm stuck with this error:

```
"[INFO] org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.databinding.UnmatchedTypeException: No type was mapped to the name AdbRuleException with namespace http://exception.common.adb.example.com"
```

If anyone have any idea where I can begin then I would be very happy! :)

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
    xmlns:impl="http://webservice.adb.example.com"  
    xmlns:intf="http://webservice.adb.example.com" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:tns1="http://exception.common.adb.example.com" 
    xmlns:tns2="http://exception.xml.adb.example.com" 
    xmlns:tns3="http://sax.xml.org" xmlns:tns4="http://lang.java" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.3
    Built on Oct 05, 2005 (05:23:37 EDT)-->
<wsdl:types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com">
        <import namespace="http://exception.common.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://lang.java"/>
        <import namespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"/>
        <import namespace="http://exception.xml.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://sax.xml.org"/>
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <complexType name="AdConnexionException">
            <sequence/>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="ArrayOf_soapenc_string">
            <complexContent>
                <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                    <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="soapenc:string[]"/>
                </restriction>
            </complexContent>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap">
        <import namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://exception.common.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://lang.java"/>
        <import namespace="http://exception.xml.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://sax.xml.org"/>
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <complexType name="mapItem">
            <sequence>
                <element name="key" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType"/>
                <element name="value" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="Map">
            <sequence>
                <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="apachesoap:mapItem"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://exception.common.adb.example.com">
        <import namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://lang.java"/>
        <import namespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"/>
        <import namespace="http://exception.xml.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://sax.xml.org"/>
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <complexType name="AdbRuleException">
            <sequence>
                <element name="errorKey" nillable="true" type="soapenc:int"/>
                <element name="errorMessage" nillable="true" type="soapenc:string"/>
                <element name="exceptionKeyMap" nillable="true" type="apachesoap:Map"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://sax.xml.org">
        <import namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://exception.common.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://lang.java"/>
        <import namespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"/>
        <import namespace="http://exception.xml.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <complexType name="SAXException">
            <sequence>
                <element name="cause" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType"/>
                <element name="exception" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType"/>
                <element name="message" nillable="true" type="soapenc:string"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://exception.xml.adb.example.com">
        <import namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://exception.common.adb.example.com"/>
        <import namespace="http://lang.java"/>
        <import namespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"/>
        <import namespace="http://sax.xml.org"/>
        <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        <complexType name="AdConnexionRuleException">
            <complexContent>
                <extension base="tns3:SAXException">
                    <sequence/>
                </extension>
            </complexContent>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="getDeadlineExceptionsByMarketIdResponse">
   <wsdl:part name="getDeadlineExceptionsByMarketIdReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDeadlinesResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getDeadlinesReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getOrderStatusResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getOrderStatusReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getStatusResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getStatusReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AdbRuleException">
    <wsdl:part name="fault" element="tns1:AdbRuleException"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="requestResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="requestReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDeadlinesByMarketIdResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getDeadlinesByMarketIdReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="cancelOrderRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="soapenc:int"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AdConnexionException">
    <wsdl:part name="fault" element="impl:AdConnexionException"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDeadlinesByMarketIdRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="soapenc:int"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getProductsByMarketIdRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getPackageInfoRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="soapenc:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="in1" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="cancelOrderResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="cancelOrderReturn" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDeadlinesRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="soapenc:int"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getRealEstatePlacementsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getRealEstatePlacementsReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getStatusRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="soapenc:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="in1" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getRealEstatePlacementsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="helloWorldResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="helloWorldReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getOrderStatusRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="soapenc:int"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getProductsByMarketIdResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getProductsByMarketIdReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getPlacementsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getPlacementsReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="AdConnexionRuleException">
    <wsdl:part name="fault" element="tns2:AdConnexionRuleException"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="helloWorldRequest">
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getDeadlineExceptionsByMarketIdRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="soapenc:int"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="requestRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getPlacementsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="in0" type="soapenc:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="in1" type="impl:ArrayOf_soapenc_string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getPackageInfoResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="getPackageInfoReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="AdConnexionService">
    <wsdl:operation name="getPackageInfo" parameterOrder="in0 in1">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getPackageInfoRequest" name="getPackageInfoRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getPackageInfoResponse" name="getPackageInfoResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionException" name="AdConnexionException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="request" parameterOrder="in0">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:requestRequest" name="requestRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:requestResponse" name="requestResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionException" name="AdConnexionException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="helloWorld">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:helloWorldRequest" name="helloWorldRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:helloWorldResponse" name="helloWorldResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getRealEstatePlacements" parameterOrder="in0">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getRealEstatePlacementsRequest" name="getRealEstatePlacementsRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getRealEstatePlacementsResponse" name="getRealEstatePlacementsResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionException" name="AdConnexionException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getPlacements" parameterOrder="in0 in1">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getPlacementsRequest" name="getPlacementsRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getPlacementsResponse" name="getPlacementsResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionException" name="AdConnexionException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getProductsByMarketId" parameterOrder="in0">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getProductsByMarketIdRequest" name="getProductsByMarketIdRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getProductsByMarketIdResponse" name="getProductsByMarketIdResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionException" name="AdConnexionException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getStatus" parameterOrder="in0 in1">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getStatusRequest" name="getStatusRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getStatusResponse" name="getStatusResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionException" name="AdConnexionException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getDeadlines" parameterOrder="in0">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getDeadlinesRequest" name="getDeadlinesRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getDeadlinesResponse" name="getDeadlinesResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionException" name="AdConnexionException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getOrderStatus" parameterOrder="in0">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getOrderStatusRequest" name="getOrderStatusRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getOrderStatusResponse" name="getOrderStatusResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionException" name="AdConnexionException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="cancelOrder" parameterOrder="in0">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:cancelOrderRequest" name="cancelOrderRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:cancelOrderResponse" name="cancelOrderResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdbRuleException" name="AdbRuleException"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionException" name="AdConnexionException"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionRuleException" name="AdConnexionRuleException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getDeadlinesByMarketId" parameterOrder="in0">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getDeadlinesByMarketIdRequest" name="getDeadlinesByMarketIdRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getDeadlinesByMarketIdResponse" name="getDeadlinesByMarketIdResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionException" name="AdConnexionException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getDeadlineExceptionsByMarketId" parameterOrder="in0">
        <wsdl:input message="impl:getDeadlineExceptionsByMarketIdRequest" name="getDeadlineExceptionsByMarketIdRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="impl:getDeadlineExceptionsByMarketIdResponse" name="getDeadlineExceptionsByMarketIdResponse"/>
        <wsdl:fault message="impl:AdConnexionException" name="AdConnexionException"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="AdConnexionServiceSoapBinding" type="impl:AdConnexionService">
    <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getPackageInfo">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="getPackageInfoRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getPackageInfoResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="request">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="requestRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="requestResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="helloWorld">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="helloWorldRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="helloWorldResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getRealEstatePlacements">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="getRealEstatePlacementsRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getRealEstatePlacementsResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getPlacements">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="getPlacementsRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getPlacementsResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getProductsByMarketId">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="getProductsByMarketIdRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getProductsByMarketIdResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getStatus">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="getStatusRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getStatusResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getDeadlines">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="getDeadlinesRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getDeadlinesResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getOrderStatus">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="getOrderStatusRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getOrderStatusResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="cancelOrder">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="cancelOrderRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="cancelOrderResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdbRuleException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdbRuleException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionRuleException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionRuleException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getDeadlinesByMarketId">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="getDeadlinesByMarketIdRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getDeadlinesByMarketIdResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getDeadlineExceptionsByMarketId">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="getDeadlineExceptionsByMarketIdRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="getDeadlineExceptionsByMarketIdResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:output>
        <wsdl:fault name="AdConnexionException">
            <wsdlsoap:fault encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="AdConnexionException" namespace="http://webservice.adb.example.com" use="encoded"/>
        </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="AdConnexionServiceService">
    <wsdl:port binding="impl:AdConnexionServiceSoapBinding" name="AdConnexionService">
        <wsdlsoap:address location="http://adb.example.com/adbXmlService/webservice/AdConnexionService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of these `use="encoded"` you should stick with [Axis 1.4](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) (or other JAX-RPC compliant implementation). Axis2 (and CXF and JAX-WS-RI for that matter) doesn't support rpc/encoded style of web services.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But can we not just change this use="encoded" to literal and it still work?

Comment: Changing WSDL will possibly make it processable by Axis2's `wsdl2java`, but the server, which implements this contract won't automatically accept not encoded messages. And by the way - this WSDL contains SOAP-Encoding types (SOAP Arrays) so changing `encoded` to `literal` won't work.

Comment: Right. So I understand that I could run into problems. But if we alter the WSDL-somewhat using RPC-literal and avoid the SOAP arrays. Do you think it would be possible that we could implement a JAX-WS complient RPC-literal web-service that "mimics" this old WS, and the clients that use it wont have to change anything in their systems? The most important thing is that our clients dont have to do any development or modifications of their own.

Comment: If you don't want to force your clients to change anything, you should be able to accept soap-encoded soap messages, I think it's not possible without heavy (e.g., XSLT) processing between message receipt and their dispatch to your endpoints...

Comment: Thanks for your time Grzegorz. Its been really helpful and potensially saving us a lot of time and trouble. I'll do some testing in soapUI to see what kind of troubles we encounter if we do the switch. Looks like we have to stay with axis1.4 then..